# How to bind or get properties from User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding

have a bit of a problem understanding some usercontrol interaction:

I've built this color picker. I have four sliders that change the color in Red, Green, & Blue (RGB and all that) as well as its opacity(alpha). When I slide these back and forth, I get a live response from the previewColor Rectangle(the fill color of the rectangle changes as I slide any of the sliders). All these elements are inside my user control.

In my main window, I have two signigicant elements, a blank canvas and a "change canvas" button. Ideally, when I play with the sliders in my user control and find a color i like, I would just click the ChangeCanvas button and the canvas background would change to match the current color of the previewRectangle.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to bind the current color of the previewRectangle to a button action that my canvas will accept. Is there any way to bind the background of my canvas to the fill of my rectangle via button action? Or is it better to pass the color property from the usercontrol to the mainwindow?

Main Window XAML & Code

```
<Window x:Class="C_ShapeCanvasV2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:schafec="clr-namespace:C_ShapeCanvasV2.SControl"
    Title="ColorCanvas" Height="393" Width="729">
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <Canvas Name="MainCanvas" MouseLeftButtonDown="MainCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" ClipToBounds="True" MouseRightButtonDown="MainCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown" Background="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="363" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="305"/>
    <!-- user control -->
    <schafec:ColorControls x:Name="colorControls" Margin="330,21,23,189"/>
    <!-- user control -->
    <Button Name="ChangeCanvas" Click="ChangeCanvas_Click" Content="Change Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="456,209,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158" />
    <Button Name="clearButton" Click="clearButton_Click" Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="498,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

</Grid>
```

```
namespace C_ShapeCanvasV2
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }       
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    private void ChangeCanvas_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //attempted -- not working
        //MainCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(clr);
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainCanvas.Children.Clear();
        MainCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

}
}
```

UserControl XAML & Code

```
 <UserControl x:Class="C_ShapeCanvasV2.SControl.ColorControls"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="153" Width="368">
<Grid Name="mainGrid" Background ="Gray" Margin="0,6,0,-6">


<!-- just an image under the previewRectangle to provide contrast for opacity purposes -->
    <Rectangle Name="underImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="24,52,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource ="/C_ShapeCanvasV2;component/Images/ops.png"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>


<!-- PreviewColor Rectangle -->
    <Rectangle Name="previewColor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="24,52,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64"/>

    <Slider Name="redSlider" Minimum="0" ValueChanged="redSlider_ValueChanged" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Maximum="255" TickFrequency="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104"/>
    <Slider Name="greenSlider" Minimum="0" ValueChanged="greenSlider_ValueChanged" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Maximum="255" TickFrequency="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104"  />
    <Slider Name="blueSlider"  Minimum="0" ValueChanged="blueSlider_ValueChanged" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Maximum="255" TickFrequency="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104"/>
    <Slider Name="alphaSlider" Minimum="0" ValueChanged="alphaSlider_ValueChanged" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Maximum="255" TickFrequency="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104"/>

    <Label Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Alpha" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Label Name="redLabel" Content="{Binding ElementName= redSlider, Path=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="318,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Name="greenLabel" Content="{Binding ElementName= greenSlider, Path=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="318,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Name="blueLabel" Content="{Binding ElementName= blueSlider, Path=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="318,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Name="alphaLabel" Content="{Binding ElementName= alphaSlider, Path=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="318,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

```
namespace C_ShapeCanvasV2.SControl
{
    public partial class ColorControls : UserControl
    {
        public Color clr;

    public ColorControls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void changeColorSystem()
    {
        clr = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToByte(alphaSlider.Value), Convert.ToByte(redSlider.Value), Convert.ToByte(greenSlider.Value), Convert.ToByte(blueSlider.Value));
        previewColor.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(clr);
    }

    //public void setColor(Color g)
    //{ 
    //    Color c = g;
    //}

    //public Color getColor()
    //{
    //    return clr;
    //}

    private void alphaSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        changeColorSystem();
    }

    private void blueSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        changeColorSystem();
    }

    private void greenSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        changeColorSystem();
    }

    private void redSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        changeColorSystem();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not be clean in my opinion, but this piece of code should work:

```
private void ChangeCanvas_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MainCanvas.Background = colorControls.previewColor.Fill;
}
```

Still you should really inform yourself about MVVM architecture to do it in a more clean/testable way.

Hope it helps.